# Trying to select every document with the same ID using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I'm trying to fetch every document which matches the same ID.

Here is what did I do:

```
app.get('/comments/:id', async (req,res)=>{
    
    let db = await connect();
    let id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);

    let results = await db.collection('comments').find({postID: id});
    console.log(results);
    res.json(results);
});
```

How to send more than one documents with the same ID?
I want to select every `postID` property with the same ID
[image]

My code while connecting with MongoDB:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

let connection_string = 'mongodb+srv://user:pass@host/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

let client = new MongoClient(connection_string, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

let db = null

export default () => {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        
        if (db /*&& client.isConnected()*/){
            resolve(db)
        }
        client.connect(err => {
            if(err){
                reject("Error while connecting: " + err)
            }
            else{
                console.log("Successful connection!")
                db = client.db("posts")
                resolve(db)
            }
        });
    })
};
```

Comment: Are you not using mongoose?

Comment: Not really, can it be done without using it?

Comment: It can be done but you have to make sure you are making the connection properly.

Comment: Could you please add the code where you are making the connection to the db?

Comment: Sure, I edited my question right now and added what's inside my db.js file.

Comment: @zx01 could you post the answer if you find the solution please?

Comment: Yeah sure. Am writing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are importing `client` from the file where you are making the connection.

```
app.get("/comments/:id", async (req, res) => {
    await client.connect();             // Simply connect() won' work.
    const db = client.db("posts");      // Specify the db here
    let id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);

    let results = await db.collection("comments").find({ postID: id }).toArray();     // Without toArray(), it returns a cursor to the array.
    console.log(results);
    res.json(results);
});
```

**db.js**

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

let connection_string = "mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.3ctoa.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

let client = new MongoClient(connection_string, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.connect((err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject("Došlo je do greške prilikom spajanja: " + err);
            } else {
                resolve("Successful connection!");
            }
        });
    });
};

module.exports = { client, db };
```

And instead of importing `connect`, import both `client` and `db` from `db.js`.

Comment: Yes but I'm already using `import connect from './db.js';` which is used to connect with my database and it is perfectly connected: `let db=await connect();`, so the problem is that the syntax is wrong with finding the same id in document. Here is my console error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle`

Comment: I also get database response: `Successful connection!`, so there's no problem with the connection.

Comment: Okay I will add the `db` file now and just give it a shot if it works for you.

Comment: I tried with to catch every document with same ID using `$all` but it still doesn't work. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I have tested my code. This works for me. Check this out [link](https://ibb.co/VLZFYgQ). Let me know if you are facing any issue.

Comment: Wow, works perfectly like I wanted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the id created by mongoose.scheme.Types.objectId, There is only one entry with that ID

Comment: I'm talking about the ID which I added manually, I used it from previous collection, so I'm creating a bond between 2 different collections, but it's not default mongo ID in this case

Comment: Then it should be enough to write.   Await db.find(yourFilter)

Comment: Okay, I edited my question, please take a look. What should I do?

Comment: Here is the error I get in a console: `Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle       
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)`